# Is Nishikyougoku Ramuko a word play of Toushinou Kyouko?

Tags: japanese-language, yuru-yuri

When writing doujinshi, Toushinou Kyouko goes by the pseudonym Nishikyougoku Ramuko. Now, her name Toushinou Kyouko is written as **歳納京子**. I'm not sure how her pseudonym is written since I wasn't able to find the original spelling for that name, but I think it would use the Kyou from Kyouko（**京**）in Nishikyougoku and Ko from Kyouko（**子**）in Ramuko. The first Nishi that I think of is（西）which means West, and the first goku I can think of is（国）which means Kingdom/Country. Thus, it would be somewhat a word play of her own name since Tou（東）in Toukyou（東**京**）means East.

Now, it is quite common for writers to use pen name that is similar to his/her real name and is related to him/her somehow. An example for this would be Joanne Rowling whose pen name was J. K. Rowling with the K. taken from her paternal grandmother's name, Kathleen. Another example would be the writer Saito Satoshi whose born name was Saito Tomohiro, more commonly known under his stage name as actor, Hiro Mizushima which uses the same Saito as in his real name. An example from another anime would be Kousaka Kirino whose pen name was Rino.

Which brings me to the question, is Nishikyougoku Ramuko really a play of her real name Toushinou Kyouko? Is my guess above correct (about the Nishikyougoku part)? What about the Ramuko part?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Nishikyougoku Ramuko (西京極ラム子) is a wordplay on Saikyouyaki Ranko (西京焼蘭子), the name of the author of the fictional magical girl series, the story within story Majokko Mirakurun (魔女っ娘ミラクるん), from which Toshinou Kyouko's doujin works are derived. We do actually know the name of the author of Majokko Mirakurun through the eyecatch featuring Toshinou Kyouoko:

[image: Eyecatch]

Nishikyougoku is the name of a [train station](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nishi-Ky%C5%8Dgoku_Station) on the Hankyu Railway Kyoto Line as well as the name of the westernmost street of [Heiankyou](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heian-ky%C5%8D#Schematic_diagram_of_Heian-ky.C5.8D), one of several former names for the city now known as Kyoto. Ramu means rum, which refers to Toshinou's favorite ice cream flavor, rum raisin. Saikyouyaki is Kyoto-style grilled fish, and Ranko is just an ordinary feminine name.

A note on the difference in pronunciation of 西京極 and 西京焼: it's how the kanjis are grouped together. 西京極 is 西 + 京極 (west + end of capital) while 西京焼 is 西京 + 焼 (West Capital + grill).

Comment: Where did you get the info on who the author of Mirakurun is? I can't find such info on Mirakurun page in Yuru Yuri wikia.

Comment: @AyaseEri Updated answer to include source.